# Why is image not showing? and how to put an image on top of the background image? html, css

Tags: html, css, image, web-deployment

I'm struggling with understanding css/html at this point. The background-image is only showing when I put it into body in css, but I would prefer to have it in a div. Also even when it's working I can't put any other image on top of it, it is just simply not showing... I checked the path and everything and it's fine, I tried to put the img in html, tried the z-index values and still nothing. I have no clue what is going on

***Any one can give me a hand with this?***

**My html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ONLINE FILM FESTIVAL</title>
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <h4>Online Film Festival</h4>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="index1.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="background-image"></div>

    
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**My css code**

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  background-color: #241825;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
  color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;

}

/* Tablet zone */
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Mobile phone zone */
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: #241825;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }

  .nav-links a {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 3.5;

  }

  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

.background-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
      rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%),
    url(images/picc1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 

}

/* .main__img--container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#main__img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
} */

/* 
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
      rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%),
    url(images/picc1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;


}

.img1 {
  background-image: url(/images/pic1.png);
  z-index: 999;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  
} */
```

The last few lines starting from .main__img--container are commented, it is just simply what I've tried and didn't work, except from "body {}"... :(

Comment: _"The last few lines starting from .main__img--container are commented, it is just simply what I've tried and didn't work"_ - there are no elements with the classes `.main__img--container` or `img1`, or any element with the ID `main__img` in the HTML you have shown us.

Comment: Sorry, yes not there is no img in the html now because I delated it but it was and it did't worked.I'm trying to put the image in css and just create the div in the html.

Answer (score 0):

a) There is no `<img>` tag in your code (?).

b) Your `background-image` element has no content, so its height will be zero by default, i.e. the background image will also have height zero and will therefore remain invisible. To make it visible, you need to set a `height` for that element. BTW, percentage heights are only relevant if the parent element's height is defined or if here is content that "creates" height.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes 
Sorry I didn't know that about %. 
There is background-image: url() in css. 
```
.background-image {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
      rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%),
    url(images/picc1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 1080px;
  width: 1920px;
```
Now I specified height and width and still not working :/

Comment: I am not talking about the height of the background-image, but of the element (div) it belongs to: If that element has height zero, you won't see the background-image. Try to add `height: 300px` to the `div` with the class `.background-image` to see what I mean. Then adjust the height setting to whatever you need.

Comment: Found a result. Of course it was a path... Stupid me... Anyway thank you so much!! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your .background-image class is specifying 100% height of what? Try adding height 100vh on your body element if you want to fill up the screen.

Alternatively just add a min-height on the element e.g 400px.

Works for me

edit:

```
<div class="background-image">
  <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9869132/pexels-photo-9869132.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working in body it is just not working when I put it in a div, I specified a height and width and still nothing :(

Comment: Mmm thats weird. I have edited my answer with a div inside background-image

Comment: I used your code, I specified the height and width in px and still nothing... I think it might be the navigation bar fault, maybe I specify one values there and now it is preventing img form occurring in a page...  But thank you anyway! I will probably start it all over again and try to figured it out from the beginning! :)